# JAXB+JPA+JAX-RS, JAXB Annotation problem

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jaxb

Hello and excuse my english!

Suppose I have this entity with this namedquery that select the name column with the jaxb annotations.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.selectAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Form p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.selectName", query = "SELECT p.id,p.name FROM Form p"),
});
@XmlRootElement
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String surname;
    ..
}
```

Suppose now i have a Rest method that executes the namedquery Person.selectName and returns XML or JSON code of the response.

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/list")
    public List<Person> getList()
    {
        //here i execute the namedquery Person.selectName
        List<Person> persons = executeNamedQuery().getList();    
        return persons;
    }
```

Now the problem is during the marshalling because there's not a @XmlRootElement annotation for the name field.
I would the output like `<Persons><Person><name>value1</name></Person><Person><name>value2</name></Person>` without the `<surname>` tags only when the namedquery Person.selectName is executed. And i can't use the @XmlTransient because the namedquery "selectAll" wants that one.
How to solve in "elegant manner"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB @XmlTransient annotation on the surname property without affecting how the JPA named query works.

```
@Column
@XmlTransient
private String surname;
```

**UPDATE**

You can solve this by creating a new class, PersonName.  This class will only have the fields you want mapped with JAXB.  This class will be returned by the getList() method, and in that method you will need to convert the List<Person> to List<PersonName>.

If you are using [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) as your JPA provider then you can also do the following:

- http://eclipselink.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-partial-eclipselink-jpa-entities.html

Comment: With the @XmlTransient annotation when I execute the namedquery "Person.selectAll" the xml ouput doesn't contain `<surname>` tags.

Comment: I thought you wanted the surname tags excluded.  Your question states  "without the <surname> tags".

Comment: ok thx @Blaise, I've solved using the `@FetchGroup` annotation http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup
The JPA entity Person must implements FetchGroupTracker